# one specific props gets undefined when component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So, this is a very weird one to me.

in my Redux store, I have to following `meal`:

```
{id: 39,
 name: "Poisson à la basque",
 restaurant: {
   id: 3,
   MID: "123456",
   name: "le pré catelan"
 }
}
```

I have a Container parent component and a child component where the parent provides props to the child.

(for simplicity purposes I won't explain here with I can't access directly the redux store from the child component. The thing is: I can't.)

```
 class Parent extends Components {
 render() {
 return (
     <Child
      mealId={this.props.meal.id}
      MID={this.props.meal.restaurant.MID} 
      />
   )
 }
}


class Child extends Components {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.MID ? (
          <p>There is a MID</p>
          ) : (
          <p>there is no MID</p>
          )
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Here is what happens: `Parent` and `Child` are called within a `Modal` component from `reactstrap`. When the `Modal` (and hence the `Parent` and `Child`components) mounts, everything works great. 
But when I trigger the event that should hide the `Modal` component (e.g. click outside the modal or on the cross on the top right corner), is get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'MID' of undefined`and it highilights the line from `Parent`: `MID={this.props.meal.restaurant.MID}`.

Notice that it only happens when I try to use any value from the `restaurant` object that is inside the `meal` object. When using values directly from the `meal` object, I get no error.

How is this possible ?

Do not hesitate to comment if I forgot to add any relevant information to help me solve the issue.

edit: here is the reducer:

```
case TOGGLE_MEAL_MODAL: {
  return {
    ...state,
    mealModalOpen: !state.mealModalOpen,
    meal: action.payload.meal
  }
}
```

where `action.payload.meal` is the kind of object mentionned  above if the modal is to be open, and `{}` if the modal is to be closed.

Comment: can you add the `reducer` ?

Comment: hi @Taki thank you for your help, I edited my question to add the reducer :)

Comment: It still seems as though you aren't sharing enough to see what the problem could be. The most obvious cause is that your action that is sent to toggle the modal does not contain a valid object within `payload.meal`, but we can't see that from this code.

Comment: @RobMasters, thank you for your comment. Yeah the thing is it is a very tricky one, I wish I could provide more information but as I really don't know what the problem could be, I am not sure what to add...

Comment: don't know if it helps: If I `console.log(this.props.meal)` in the parent and `console.log(this.props.MID)`in the child in `componentDidMount` for both of them, the child log displays first.

Comment: @RobMasters the action.payload value is: `{meal: {}}`

Comment: can you add the `state` you're passing to the reducer ? ( the initialState ), and you can `console.log(action)` inside `case TOGGLE_MEAL_MODAL: {` ( before the return to see if the action is returning an object containing  `restaurant` and `MID`

Comment: @Taki it returns `{meal: {}}`. changing the initalState to `{meal:{restaurant:{MID: ""}}}`solves the issue. Thank you !

Comment: @JulesCorb well then you've just answered your own question. You're setting the meal in redux state to be an empty object and then somehow expecting to read a `meal.restaurant.MID` value within the Parent component. You either need to fix your reducer so you can't wipe the state (perhaps merge the object rather than replacing it) or pass a valid meal object when toggling the modal.

Comment: yeah that's exactly the problem. But what I still don't get is: why does React tries to read the `meal` object in my redux store when the component unmounts ?

Answer (score 0):

When the modal unmounts, it changes the `meal` object to `{}`in the redux store. Hence `this.props.meal.restaurant.MID` won't work; unless the empty object looks like so:

```
{meals: 
  {
    restaurant: {
      MID: ""
    }
  }
}
```

so that it remains a valid object.